# Unable to click HTML button in a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that I am unable to click an HTML button that is being displayed via a javascript loop.

Every few seconds while the loop is updated, if you click the button it doesn't run the javascript function as it is supposed to.

My current code:

```
var alertUser = function() {
    alert("Button clicked");
}

window.setInterval(function() {     
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    document.write('<input type="button" value="Alert" onclick="alertUser()">');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: More context is needed - in particular, why are you resetting the button HTML once per second?

Comment: Once the load event has occurred, a call to *document.write* will first clear the entire contents of the document, including the script block that defines *alertUser*.

Comment: This is just an example of my code. I am changing a timer in the same loop as the button is in.

Comment: Seems to work correctly in JSFiddle, provided the code is included directly in the head or body, rather than in a window.onload statement. http://jsfiddle.net/hyFud/1/

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `document.write()` in this day and age unless you are constructing a child window (which you aren't). Doing so is probably causing your whole page to be overwritten and possibly disabling any script that you've added.

I really don't understand what you are trying to do here, but why aren't you doing this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {     
 document.body.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Alert" onclick="alertUser()">';
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hyFud/2/